# How to link child View state to menus using FocusedValues

Tags: macos, swiftui

SwiftUI newbie here.  I'm struggling to understand how `@FocusedBinding` and `FocusedValues` work when building menus for a MacOS app. I'm trying to build the [Apple HIG UI pattern](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/toolbars/#:%7E:text=Make%20every%20toolbar%20item%20available%20as%20a%20menu%20command.) with buttons in the window toolbar for changing the list view, and matching menu items in the View menu. Much like Finder windows have the four different view modes.

I have gone through the [Apple's Landmarks tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui), the [Frameworks Engineer's example code in Apple dev forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651748), and [Majid's tutorial](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2021/03/03/focusedvalue-and-focusedbinding-property-wrappers-in-swiftui/).

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusedvalues) says `FocusedValues` is *"a collection of state exported by the focused view and its ancestors."* I assume the collection is global and I can set a `focusedValue` in any child View, and read or bind to any of the FocusedValues from anywhere in my code.

Therefore I don't understand why my first example below works, but the second one doesn't?

This works:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestiApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 300)
                .onAppear {
                    NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing = false
                }
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
        .commands {
            MenuCommands()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    // In the working version of the code selectedView is defined here
    // in the ContentView, which is a direct child of the WindowGroup 
    // that has the .commands modifier.
    @State private var selectedView: Int = 0
    // For demonstration purposes I have simplified the authorization
    // code to a hardcoded boolean.
    private var isAuthorized: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        switch isAuthorized {
        case true:
            // focusedValue is set here to the selectedView binding.
            // I don't really understand why do it here, but it works.
            AuthorizedView(selectedView: $selectedView)
                .focusedValue(\.selectedViewBinding, $selectedView)
        default:
            NotYetAuthorizedView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct AuthorizedView: View {
    // selectedView is passed to this view as an argument and 
    // bound from ContentView.
    @Binding var selectedView: Int

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Something here")
            Text("Something more")
            Text("Even more")
        }
        .toolbar {
            // The Picker element sets and gets the bound selectedView value
            Picker("View", selection: $selectedView) {
                Text("View 1").tag(0)
                Text("View 2").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}


struct NotYetAuthorizedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You need permission to access this ")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}


struct MenuCommands: Commands {

    private struct MenuContent: View {
        // Command menu binds the selectedView value through focusedValues.
        // MenuContent is a View, because otherwise the binding doesn't
        // work (I read there's a bug in SwiftUI...).
        @FocusedBinding(\.selectedViewBinding) var selectedView: Int?
        
        var body: some View {
            Button("View 1") {
                selectedView = 0
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("1")
            
            Button("View 2") {
                selectedView = 1
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("2")
        }
    }

    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(before: .toolbar) {
            MenuContent()
        }
    }
}


struct SelectedViewBinding: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Binding<Int>
}

extension FocusedValues {
    var selectedViewBinding: SelectedViewBinding.Value? {
        get { self[SelectedViewBinding.self] }
        set { self[SelectedViewBinding.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

But if I make the following changes to ContentView and AuthorizedView, the project compiles fine but the binding between `selectedView` and the command menus no longer works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // selectedView definition has been removed from ContentView
    // and moved to AuthorizedView.
    private var isAuthorized: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        switch isAuthorized {
        case true:
            AuthorizedView()
            // Also setting the focusedValue here has been removed
        default:
            NotYetAuthorizedView()
        }
    }
}

struct AuthorizedView: View {
    // Moved selectedView definition here
    @State private var selectedView: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Something here")
            Text("Something more")
            Text("Even more")
        }
        .toolbar {
            Picker("View", selection: $selectedView) {
                Text("View 1").tag(0)
                Text("View 2").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .focusedValue(\.selectedViewBinding, $selectedView)
            // I am now setting the focusedValue here, which seems 
            // more logical to me...
        }
    }
}
```

I like the second example better, because the `selectedView` state is encapsulated in the `AuthorizedView` where it belongs.